# How to call _trackPageView from Google Tag Manager for an AJAX page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a page loaded in via AJAX.

In Google Analytics I could have just called `gaq.push('_trackPageView','/someurl')` in my AJAX success function. However I can't seem to find a way to do this when implementing GA via Google Tag Manager.

The only alternative seems to be a ["virtual page view" event](http://www.swellpath.com/2013/09/google-analytics-virtual-pageviews-la-google-tag-manager/), which isn't exactly what I'm after: 
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

on the Ajax success, do:

```
dataLayer.push({
'event':'sendVirtualPageview',
'vpv':'/blah/blah'
});
```

The 'event' is just to send the virtual pageview to GTM.  It's not a traditional, although it could be, Google Analytics event.

You should be able to folllow the rest of the tutorial to create your rule and setup the tag type.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it out yet. As soon as I do I'll accept :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you enable Virtual Page Views on your Google Analytics tag in GTM.

**GTM v2:**

Go to the Variables page. Enable the Event variable `{{event}}` by ticking the `Event` checkbox inside Utilities under the Enable Built-in Variables heading.

Create a variable named `Virtual Url` with type `Data Layer Variable` and set the Data Layer Variable Name to `"virtualUrl"`.

Go to the Triggers page. Create a trigger named `Virtual Page View` with type `Custom Event` and set the Event name to `"virtualPageView"`.

Create a tag `GA Virtual Page Views` with product Google Analytics Universal. Set your Tracking ID `UA-xxxxxx-xx`. Set the track type to `Pageview`.

Under More Settings > Fields to set, click `+ Add Field`.
Set Field Name to `page` with value `{{Virtual Url}}`.

You can add additional fields here, such as title, UTM campaign etc. Add variables then add them here.

Click Continue. Under Fire On, click `More`. In the triggers popup, tick `Virtual Page View`. Click Save.

Click Create Tag.

**GTM v1:**

Create a macro `{{Virtual Url]}` referring to dataLayer variable `"virtualUrl"`.

Create a `{{Virtual Page View}}` rule as `{{event}} equals "virtualPageView"`.

You should already have an `{{event}}` macro, but if you don't, create one using the dataLayer variable `"event"`.

Updates to your Google Analytics tag:

- More Settings > Basic Config, tick `"Virtual Page Path"` and use macro `{{Virtual URL}}`.
- Remove the `{{All Pages}}` firing rule.
- Add the `{{Virtual Page View}}` firing rule.

**GA Fields:**

`page` = the path portion of a URI. eg. /blog/topic/post.html

`title` = used to specify the `<title>` contents

`campaignMedium` = used to specify the URI `utm_medium`

`campaignSource` = used to specify the URI `utm_source`

`campaignTerm` = used to specify the URI `utm_term`

`campaignContent` = used to specify the URI `utm_content`

`campaignName` = used to specify the URI `utm_campaign`

**Usage:**

In your web app, call it like so:

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'virtualPageView',
    'virtualUrl': '/relative/page/path',
    'virtualTitle': 'My page title'
});
```

You can rename any of the variables above - this is just an example based on how we do it.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.simoahava.com/ He has some great blog posts about configuring GTM